# I am using mongoDb with Sails.js, finding diffucuties in sorting the records

Tags: mongodb, sorting, sails.js

Sorting of records gives irreverent results I am using mongoDB with sails.js

Here is the syntax:

```
 model.find(conditions).sort({ "title": -1 })
```

Comment: whats the -1 supposed to do?

Comment: -1 is or desc order and 1 for asc

Comment: Could you be more explicit ? What are the records ? What is the desired output and what output are you getting ?

Comment: The main issue with case sensitivity If I have records like Naresh, nar, aakash, Amit, Ball. I am getting the out put as Amit, Ball, Naresh, aakash, nar, But it should be Amit, aakash, Ball, nar, naresh

Comment: You could try to use `title desc` but don't think you will get another results.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931177/mongo-db-sorting-with-case-insensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sails supports native MongoDB queries so yo can use MongoDB Aggregation framework.

```
model.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.aggregate(
        //...
    );
});
```

Take a look here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: This is much better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the lodash global to perform the sort instead, like this:

```
model.find(conditions).exec(function(err, records) {
    _.sortBy(records, function(blah){ return your_custom_logic_here; });
});
```

Comment: Don't think it's a good solution. If database will contain about a million records you will fetch all records first and then will perform sorting. It will require lot of memory and will create issues with loading time.

Comment: Agreed. But the default sort will not allow the OP to perform the custom action. SO scratching my head...