# How to perform a sorting with case insensitive in the sails js framework?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, sails.js, mongodb-query, sails-mongo

```
model.find({city: city, sort: 'cityname ASC'}, function(err, cityList){});
```

the above code giving the correct sorting list but whenever the city is in both uppercase or lowercase like Coimbatore,bangalore,Chennai it gives the output as Chennai,Coimbatore,bangalore but i need the output as bangalore,Chennai, Coimbatore like that. Please help me to get the output as i wanted.. and advace thanking to you all..

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931177/mongo-db-sorting-with-case-insensitive

Comment: is there any solution yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error in MongoDB - AFAIk there isn't really a solution for it as of now

- similar SO question: [Mongo DB sorting With case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931177/mongo-db-sorting-with-case-insensitive)
- mongoDB JIRA issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

**Update:** A workaround I've found - store the strings a second time only upper or only lower case and sort by that property: http://futurestud.io/blog/case-insensitive-sorting-with-mongoose-and-mongodb/