# Wrong order when using System.Linq.Dynamic with MongoDB collection

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I use `System.Linq.Dynamic` to order a MongoDB collection.

```
mongoCollection.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Name ASC");
```

But the lowercase names gets ordered after the capital cased names, so the items are returned something like this.

- Ape
- Cat
- Dog
- alligator
- ant
- beetle

I rather expected this:

- alligator
- ant
- Ape
- beetle
- Cat
- Dog

Is there a way to get the correct order?

Comment: MongoDB sorting is Case sensetive

Comment: Maybe duplicated with [Mongo DB sorting With case insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931177/mongo-db-sorting-with-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
mongoCollection.AsQueryable().ToList().OrderBy(c=>c.Name.ToLower());
```

Comment: Wouldn't that load all objects in the collection?

Comment: I guess he wants to order in MongoDB not in memory

Comment: @Peyman, that wouldn't be very practical. What if I have one million objects in the collection?

Comment: @Adrian, have you checked the link that already added in your question comment? It's duplicate question, you can find your answer in that link